# Trying to print developer story results in a blank page

Tags: bug, status-completed, developer-story, print

I have not been able to print [my *developer story*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/2751596) for quite some time now. I have tried printing both CV and story pages. The browsers that I have tried are Firefox v92.0 and [Brave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brave_(web_browser)) v1.29.81 on [macOS v11.5.2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Big_Sur) (Big Sur).

Here’s how it looks when I hit the print button or select *Print* from the context menu.

[image: The print dialog shows a preview of the page, but the page is completely blank. In the top-right corner, it says “1 sheet of paper” as the total count.]

The URL I am trying to print my dev story from is: https://stackoverflow.com/story/tbking

Comment: Well, it looks like it looks okay in Chrome, but in Firefox Nightly 94.0a1 I see [this](//i.stack.imgur.com/SvjQk.png). It’s not blank, but the content is not centered and is partially cut off. The Developer Story page is also not responsive yet, so I assume that print optimization will have to wait until it’s responsive. Which Firefox version are you using?

Comment: @yivi I see now. I can get it to center when I scale down the print. It looks like you’ve used a ~50 % scaling. But it looks tiny, and quite bad in general when printed, e.g. blurry images nearly everywhere.

Comment: Ah, now I see. But I still cannot reproduce the totally blank page, neither with the settings shown in the post, nor with any other settings. It also says “4 sheets of paper” for me, not “1 sheet of paper” in the dialog.

Comment: That's interesting to know. I have added the browser and system version in the question

Comment: I am able to print other pages on Stack Overflow, like [this question](https://imgur.com/a/74sIbLH) but not the developer story.

Comment: Okay, thanks for checking. I can try printing my dev story from other systems. Hopefully I will find something wrong setting on my system sooner or later.

Comment: I just checked and I don't think my reproduction steps were very detailed. I am trying to print by clicking the Print button on the right side of this page https://stackoverflow.com/story/tbking. From your screenshots it seems like you are printing from https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/2751596. [Here's the button](https://imgur.com/a/iIsAoEf) I am using.

Comment: Got it. In a print view, the developer story becomes invisible, and there’s a separate developer story specifically for print. The first one has a `print:d-none` class, the second one a `d-none` and `print:d-block` class. The `d-none print:d-block` is supposed to make the element visible only in print, but unfortunately, both selectors have the same specificity, so the `d-none` style overrides the `print:d-block` style since it’s defined later. Changing the selector of `.print\:d-block { display: block !important; }` selector to `.d-none.print\:d-block` works. `!important` can be removed.

Comment: Was able to repro in FF 92 and Edge 93

Comment: Looks like the code release today fixed this

Comment: Yes, I could print it today. How is the question marked resolved in these cases?

Comment: I've already marked it resolved (the red tags are moderator/staff only)

Comment: On that page: *"Find me on Github"* should be *"Find me on GitHub"*. [GitHub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub).

Comment: Thanks @PeterMortensen. Unconventional use of StackOverflow Meta comments to point out a typo in my developer story bio.